# is there a function to know if a window has a flashinfo blinking orange on taskbar?

Tags: c#, winapi

i'm trying to make an application that loop into a process name to check if it has a notification blinking orange in task bar to show it later in foreground desktop for user by using the user32 - "SetForegroundWindow" function.

this is just an exemple of a window in taskbar that i need to get stat if its blinking or not

[image]

i'm expecting to have a true/false value to return

any idea ?

Comment: I don't think there is, but since an app is generally flashing itself, if it wanted to come to the front, wouldn't it do so itself?

Comment: no it doesn't show up, imaging having 50 window opened in the taskbar ! the user will try to find the notified window and for saving time its not good

Comment: This isn't a state of the process or window. It happens when a process calls `FlashWindow` or `FlashWindowEx`.

Comment: how can i check if a FlashWindow or FlashWindowEx is called

Comment: If it doesn't show up, then the app thinks it's not needed, why would you want to change that? And like I said, there is no API that will give you this info.

Comment: @DavidG ok thank you for your time and response

Comment: The whole reason the flash exists, rather than throwing the window up front, is to prevent windows from stealing focus at times the user doesn't want it to happen (which is virtually always). Even if you were able to find out the window was flashing, keep in mind that you might not be able to actually do anything meaningful about it -- in particular, the flashing might be the *result* of `SetForegroundWindow` being deferred, and explicitly calling it could just do more of the same.

Answer (score 3):

[`RegisterShellHookWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registershellhookwindow) to get the `HSHELL_FLASH` notification.

Comment: how can i use it in a function please ?

Comment: @Androi_Begin Start by following the information presented in the documentation.